# Visual Studio - step through when not in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am looking through a huge amount of some one else's code (all class libraries) which is pretty complex for me. One of the reasons is the previous developer has many, many nested methods (if such a term exists). For example

```
string = DoThis(CheckThat(WasThisRight(DontForgetTo(AhYouNearlyDidntDo("")ToString().ToLower().Replace("this", "that").ExtensionMethodChaosBegins();
```

Now, I can select the method with the mouse and hit <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>12</kbd> but it's less efficient then just pressing <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>11</kbd> (for a few reasons).

So, is it possible to step through code when not in debug mode but whilst in design mode?

Comment: If you want to step throught the code run it in debug mode.  If you are in design mode, then code is not being ran, besides you cannot modify the source code and step through code in certain situations.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I can't provide any insight on this one but just wanted to say that your example code made my day :D Funny stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to do this in debug mode. Remember that there's also <kbd>F10</kbd> for stepping over lines you don't want to step into, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> if you've stepped into something you want to get out of.

You already know of <kbd>F12</kbd> to go to declaration, but remember also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> which will show all places where the member is used.

Comment: But I can't run a class library alone (or can I)? Or would I have to create a Test first, or create a quick console app to call the libraries?

Comment: @DaveRook That's right. You will need to write something that calls these methods if you want to step through the code. No way around that.

Comment: Right, well that answers everything for me and is good to know. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper's refactor tools might be a Godsend in a situation like this.

Comment: We're not allowed it at work; basically if it's not on the MSDN library, we don't get access! Thank you though. +1 for good information

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find [Debugger Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/debuggercanvas.aspx) useful. It shows functions in their own little bubbles and shows the call stack visually, left to right, of the code you're working in

It's even in the MSDN!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a dry run of the code by using `f12` to "jump into" a called method. To jump back out to the calling method when you hit a "return", you can use `ctrl+minus`. This allows you to manually emulate the stack when walking the source code.

(Note that ctrl+minus actually jumps the cursor position through a stack of saved states, so if you move the cursor around too much in the called method, you will end up with multiple stacked states that you have to cycle through before you will actually return to the calling function)